# Any suggestions for better way to address run-time Vulkan errors not accompanied with much information?

Tags: vulkan

I have been coding in Vulkan API for couple of months. I followed Vulkan samples and tutorials to set up all needed debug layers and debug extension to make debugging convenient, like:

- include "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation" in layers
- use vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT() to register a report callback

However, there are a lot of Vulkan run-time errors / crashes that only tell you which API function returns a failure code, for example:

- vkCreatePipelineLayout() returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
- vkQueuePresentKHR() returns VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST

It is still quite time-consuming to address the final reason of these errors.

**I understand this is the performance-oriented way that Vulkan API is designed, but still would like to know if anyone has some tips to make Vulkan bug-fixing slightly easier?**

Comment: Loss of device can happen for any reason, whether due to your program's or something beyond its control. And object initialization failure can happen for "implementation-specific reasons" which again, may be outside of your control.

Comment: AFAICT drivers are allowed to push their own messages to Debug Report accompanying the `VK_ERROR_*`. They just choose not to. So I would say there is no API design problem here.

Comment: Thanks for all your information and I think this is so far what all Vulkan developers have to be used to. There are, however, several errors / crashes I made are actually caused by simple invalid-parameter mistakes, I was wondering why none of validation layers and debug report did not catch this earlier by sort of sanity check, hope in future Vulkan drivers can make it better.

Comment: @HongkunWang: Drivers are never going to "make it better"; that's not their *job*. Vulkan specifically does not have very much error checking, and the driver is almost never required to verify validity of any parameters or objects. That's why validation layers exist. If you ran into some valid usage you violated that the layers didn't find, you should file a bug report on them at the appropriate project on GitHub.

Comment: @Nicol Thank you for your suggestions!.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions given by few experienced Vulkan developers, I try to answer my question (although not sure if 100% accurate):

There is no "better way" to make Vulkan debugging easier due to the fact that invalid parameters may cause run-time error / crash without detailed error information. Less error checking is Vulkan's trade-off for performance and we have to face it and do coding carefully.

Comment: The validation layers are supposed to catch invalid parameters; for debugging that kind of issue they should be just as good as anything a driver could do. I'd suggest double-checking that you've got the validation layers enabled correctly (if you intentionally do something obviously wrong, do you get a debug callback from the validation layers?) and that you're using recent versions of them. If you're able to confirm that your code misused Vulkan and the validation layers failed to notice it, please file a bug!

Comment: @Jesse, thanks for your suggestions. Yes it does caught intentional wrong parameters. My validation layer and debug report actually can catch about 90% percent of invalid parameters, but this percent varies from platforms to platforms. Here is the order (from high to low): GeForce, Radeon, Intel Graphics, Android (Adreno / PowerVR). Since when I add a new functions, I always test it on all above devices, it's quite common to see that app runs on several platforms and failed on others.

Comment: @HongkunWang Validation Layers are not platform dependent (assuming you are using the same version nuber, they are the same). Unless you mean something else by "my validation layer".

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check all the run-time errors I have made.

Comment: @All  It a silly mistake I have made that incidentally turn off the validation layer recently after I start building my app for macOS and iOS via MoltenVK. When I tried to exclude some unsupported debug features for MoltenVK, I over-exclude some code related validation. Now invalid parameters can be caught by validation layers. Thanks everyone, Cheers!